# What if I do not know how to design the circuit board for my idea?

Tags: design-patent, design

Let's say I had thought of the idea of a "computer mouse", but I did not know how to design the circuitry.

Would it be a safe thing to solicit the services of an expert?  What type of protections should I consider?

Can I submit the patent's idea before contracting this work out?

Answer (score 1):

I've contracted engineers and product development firms several times. The standard agreement is that any patentable content developed during the course of the agreement would be owned by you (or your company) since you are paying for the work. You need to make sure this is clearly spelled out in the contract, but as I said, it is pretty much standard at least in the US and the UK. If patentable material is generated, the contracted engineer may be listed as an inventor, but the assignee would be you or your firm.

Comment: Don't forget the NDA

Comment: @DonQuiKong  Excellent point. Every contract I've had with a design firm includes confidentiality, but before you get there you need an NDA just to discuss the project parameters.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Not to mention,  possibly, "non-compete".  In theory, one might compete without unlawfully disclosing the proprietary invention, and not every NDA includes a non-compete clause.

Comment: @Upnorth good point. I don't know how common non-compete clauses are in these cases (might prove difficult for a contractor to keep many non compete clauses), but it's worth to think about one.

Comment: @Upnorth No product development firm will agree to a non-compete clause unless you represent a huge amount of continuing business. Maybe for Microsoft or General Motors. For a small firm, no way.

Comment: Regarding your example - If you were the first person to think of a computer mouse as a cool thing to exist, you would not have invented a computer mouse. Over the history of mice there have been several completely different principles that made them work. Someone else could design the details, but without you coming up with at least one way it could work, you would be not an inventor. That doesn't mean you can't hire a contractor to invent for you and you still be the applicant/owner/patentee.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite  I'm not sure what your comment is getting at. As I said, if the contractor generates the patentable idea they would be the inventor and the hiring individual is the assignee. I completely agree that an idea for an invention is not actually an invention. Only the implementation can be invented.

Comment: Great information, thanks for the discussion.  I believe this idea would not require complicated circuitry and software, as a mouse and computer would.

If this doesn't qualify for an invention, what about on-line circuitry design?  Does anyone have experience designing and patenting their own product?  If so, any recommendations on a reputable service?

Comment: @EricShain You are 100% correct. I was trying to note that something as vague as 'there ought to be a thing you move on a horizontal surface that correspondingly moves a computer cursor or pointer on a screen', did not constitute inventing something.

Comment: Thanks again all.  

What about on-line circuitry design? Does anyone have experience designing and patenting their own product? If so, any recommendations on a reputable service?

Comment: @BA_Booracus  I don't know what you are referring to with "on-line circuitry design". Is this circuit design services you contract with through the internet or software that resides on-line?